# CSS :hover is not clearing when navigating to a new tab

Tags: javascript, css, wcag

I am developing a WCAG compliant website and we implemented links that navigate to a new tab by following the pattern suggested on the WCAG website.

Below is a working example of the issue: (Both Google and IE)

http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/G201/new-window.html

If you hover over the link and then click, the new tab appears. When you click back on the original tab, the hover remains open until you click somewhere.

I am not sure if this is a bug or by design, but what would be an appropriate WCAG method of clearing it.   Using Javascript might work, but I am not familiar with how to do the hooks.

I was thinking about a transition on the hover that after x seconds, it fades away.  Would that be okay for WCAG compliance?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Pop-Up Warning</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
margin-left:2em;
margin-right:2em;
}
:focus
{
outline: 0;
}
a.info
{
position:relative;
z-index:24;
background-color:#ccc;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none
}
a.info:hover, a.info:focus, a.info:active
{
z-index:25;
background-color:#ff0
}
a.info span
{
position: absolute;
left: -9000px;
width: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
a.info:hover span, a.info:focus span, a.info:active span 
{
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:1em; left:1em; width:12em;
border:1px solid #0cf;
background-color:#cff;
color:#000;
text-align: center
}
div.example
{
margin-left: 5em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Pop-Up Warning</h1>
<p>
This is an example of an <a  target="_blank" class="info" href="http://example.com/popup_advisory_technique.html"><strong>External link</strong><span>Opens a new window</span></a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using client side routing? If so, it may keep states between page navigation

Comment: It's a simple <a href="xxx" class="info" target="_blank">Hello<span>Open in new window</span></a>

Comment: Please provide some code to reproduce your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the `target="_blank"` attribute will open the page in a new tab, and keep the states in current tab unchanged. You can remove the `target="_blank"`, and open the page in current tab. Or you can use javascript to clear the focus state in the click callback

```html
<a target="_blank" onclick="this.blur();">Hello<span>Open in new window</span></a>
```

Comment: That could be good.  This is on a ton of links however; is there a way to do it once with a javascript hook?  I will do this is necessary, but looking for a quickfix first.

Comment: you can add the onclick event listener in batch, just make sure you select the right `a` elements...
`document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', (e) => e.target.blur()))`